# Mac OS X Lion / Mountain Lion Cache Miss Profiling

Tags: ios, profiling, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion, shark

Is there any tool to profile cache misses on Mac OS X Lion and iOS.
If you know how to do that in instruments please help.

Shark (CHUD package) do not install on Mac OS X Lion and later, so I can't use shark. 
At the same time I can't find the functionality of cache miss profiler in Instruments.

Comment: Have you looked at at zoom http://www.rotateright.com/ (not free) or valgrind http://www.valgrind.org/ ? No iOS support on either, though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the instrument you are looking for is called "VM Operations". To get it, first create a new document using the Blank template in Instruments, then click the + in the toolbar and choose VM Operations as the instrument to add in the panel that appears.

Note that to make this work, you will need to choose either deferred or windowed mode. You can change these settings in File->Record Options…

Answer (score -1):

what about [Core Data Cache Misses instrument](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/CoreDataCacheMissesInstrument/CoreDataCacheMissesInstrument.html)  for OSX ?

Comment: memory cache have nothing to do with core data